Move a specific cell data in a row from a sheet to another sheet
I have a source sheet which contains records of employees who borrows company equipment for work. The data on this source sheet (sheet2) contains the data of current user, details of the equipment and dates in row format. For previous user records, it is located just to the right side of the current users. So basically the previous records will show "Previous user 1", Previous user 2" an so on.
In sheet1 which is where I filter the details of the current user base on the unique tag of the equipment.
For example in sheet1 in my sample data, I filter out TV-002, I need the name, ID, start date and return date of the equipment, then move these data to the next blank cells in the "Previous Users" range.
Here is a link of my Google sheet screenshots.
Sheet screenshots link

Here is my sample Google sheet data
Google Sheets sample data
I am a beginner in app script so I am not sure to do this, since the codes that I have tried will not allow me to put the data on the intended range which is in the previous users part.
This is the code that copied from someone and I tested but  its only moving one cell value (B5) to the target sheet and its in the wrong row as well.
function moveRows(){

    // Start: Get the data to move

        // Get the current sheet object
        var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
        
        // Get the number of the row to move
        var rowToMove = sourceSheet.getRange(5,1,1,1).getRow();
        Logger.log("rowToMove: " + rowToMove);

        // Get the range to move
        var rangeToCopyFrom = sourceSheet.getRange(rowToMove, 2, 1, 1);
    
    // End: Get the data to move

    // Start: Copy and paste the data
    
        // Get the target sheet
        var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
        
        // Get last row in target sheet
        var lastColInTargetSheet = targetSheet.getLastColumn();
        Logger.log("lastColInTargetSheet: " + lastColInTargetSheet);
        
        // Get range to paste to
        var rangeToPasteTo = targetSheet.getRange(lastColInTargetSheet + 1, 1, 1, 1);
        
        // Copy and paste the data
        rangeToCopyFrom.copyTo(rangeToPasteTo, {contentsOnly:true});
    
    // End: Copy and paste the data

}; // End: moveRows


For what it's worth, I wouldn't organize the data like this in the first place. I'd keep it in a tabular format, where everything would be organized in a single row. You could use spreadsheet functions to identify a chain of users based on date timestamps.

I understand your point however we already have tons of data and it would take much more time to organize it that's why I'm looking for a script that does as stated in the post.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. While a link to an external resource, such as a spreadsheet, might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained.  You should describe the spreadsheet in the question body, including sample data.

Perhaps you could add that information and any other info into your question so that everyone  will know.

@Cooper Yes, I edited my question and included screenshots with information of what I wanted.

Try this:
function moveRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  ssh.getRange(5, 2, 1, 1).copyTo(tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
}


Its still only moving data in sheet1 B5 and wrong cell in sheet2. I need the data in sheet1 G5, H5, J5 and K5 moved to which ever row in the target sheet that has the F5 (TV-002). Basically filter first which row in sheet2 has the TV-002, which is a unique word in sheet2 column E, and move those data in sheet1 (G5, H5, J5 and K5) to the next blank cell on which row the TV-002 is located, (T4:W4) in sheet2 in this case.

How about this?
function moveRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(5, 2, 1, 10).getValues()[0];
  const valuesToMove = sourceValues.slice(5);
  valuesToMove.splice(2, 1);
  const itemTag = sourceValues[4];
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const itemTags = targetSheet.getRange(3, 5, targetSheet.getLastRow() - 3 + 1, 1)
    .getValues()
    .flat();
  const rowToMove = itemTags.indexOf(itemTag) + 3;
  const colToMove = targetSheet.getRange(rowToMove, targetSheet.getMaxColumns())
    .getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS)
    .getColumn() + 1;
  targetSheet.getRange(rowToMove, colToMove, 1, valuesToMove.length)
    .setValues([valuesToMove]);

  // additional code
  targetSheet.getRange('C' + rowToMove).setValue('Defective');
  targetSheet.getRange('H' + rowToMove).setValue('On Site');
}


In relation to this, how can I replace specific data on the same row of the item tag? Like for example in source sheet2, I will need to replace cell value on Condition column with "Defective" and Location column to "On Site" for example after I move the details of that item tag to previous user.

How about additional code?

Perfect! This worked again as intended. Thank you again! I cannot mark this as an answer yet since I don't have enough reputation.
